# how to apply a cloth modifier on a different animated position?

Tags: modifiers, rigging, armature, cloth-simulation

[image]
got this, however, when I apply the simplecloth modifier this happens
[image]
WHY? why does it apply the avatar armature twice?

Right now I rig the clothing to the armature.
Then, while running the cloth simulator, I move the avatar to a sitting position. (this way I get all folds and creases as desired).
When the simulation is done and the avatar sits, I want to apply the cloth modifier with the above results.

I know I don't apply the cloth modifier in the default T-pose, but I can't get the creases and folds natural when I stand up (compared to sitting down).
Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: Please use the built-in image adding system. Thank you!

Comment: The reason is that the *Cloth* modifier is not the first on the stack (top-down wise). If you apply it you will get a blue warning in the status bar. I am not sure what you want to achieve and if it's possible. It's like this: you have your modeled mesh that is deformed by the armature modifier, then modified by the next 2 (the red one is temp. inactive), and then deformed by the Cloth mod. If you apply it then it deforms your *modeled base* mesh. This changed mesh is deformed by the armature mod & the next modifiers. If you want to apply the Cloth mod you need to apply all mods before first.